# Trying to set up wifi Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 16.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu on my mac book pro with retina display and am able to dual boot into both Ubuntu and OS X with no issues. The current problem I'm having is that I cannot seem to find any networks whatsoever when I'm in Ubuntu, but on OS X, I'm connected to my home WiFi. Please Help!
Wireless card: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution posted at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Oneiric#Wireless .

But this is for 12.04, you can try.